# How to get keywords in a text in excel?

Tags: excel, automation, html, keyword

I have an excel sheet. One column of the sheet has rows of textual data. I need to find out the keywords in the text in each row and then put the keywords in another column.

There is this http://textalyser.net/ website which can give me the keywords for a certain text but I am not sure how to use it automatically to find the key words in the text of each row in Excel.

Is there any way to do it automatically. Is there any other way without writing the code to achieve the end result.

Comment: Excel is not really designed for long texts that you put in a tiny cell. Use Word instead, is my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it does not matter as the text I have in the rows is not that long. May be 50 words at max in any row. I am wondering what difference will it make in solving the problem if I copy the table and paste it in Word.